# Message queue in POSIX

Tags: c, linux, posix, ipc

If I have a message queue

`mqd_t m; 
    m = mq_open(NAME,O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666, NULL);`

Is it possible to send a message on it and the same process to perform a receive on the
same message ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Why not? It could. See the official mannual here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mq_open.3.html
The argument O_RDWR means:

> O_RDWR Open the queue to both send and receive messages.

Like a file object, you could read and write it in one process.